# Today Extension: Core data Access

Tags: ios, core-data, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

1. I am trying to add a today extension to my app.
2. My app includes a cocoaPod (our own cocoapod) which sets up the core data model for our app.
3. I setup the today extension to use our pod.
4. On running the today extension target, I get an error for this line.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyModel" withExtension:@"momd"]];
```

The error is that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyModel" withExtension:@"momd"]` is nil.

I have set up the group for the app and the extension in the developer store. Wonder why it cannot find the data model in the app bundle?

-- Thanks

Comment: Select extension target, then build phases and search for `xcdatamodeld` file. Can you see it there?

Comment: Hi @alexbrytnik, I am going to check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You must create app-group for today extension and change storeURL to a location contained in your shared App Group folder:

```
NSURL *directory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.YourGroupName"];
NSURL *storeURL = [directory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourAppName.sqlite"];
```

For swift: https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-shared-coredata-storage-for-app-groups-447b4ba43eec#.au9abo8v5

For objective-C: https://github.com/atomicbird/iOS-Extension-Demo

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tip. I am going to try this out and update here.